# how can i fix this? it tells me that optional "!" is not needed

Tags: swift, swift-optionals

```
var camera = UIImage(named: "1")! 
var city = UIImage(named: "2")! 
var animals = UIImage(named: "3")! 
var flowers = UIImage(named: "4")! 
var stand = UIImage(named: "5")! 
var urban = UIImage(named: "6")!
```

it seems normal until i run the project.

Comment: Are you sure you have images called `1`, `2`, `3` and so on?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Declare images like

```
let camera: UIImage = UIImage(named: "1") ?? UIImage()
```

and then you will be sure that even when there is no image named "1" the app won't crash.

You can also create UIImage extension

```
extension UIImage {

    static let camera: UIImage = UIImage(named: "1") ?? UIImage()

}
```

and use images like that:

```
yourImageView.image = .camera
```

Comment: "1" is a hardcoded value, it's much better to correct the issue with that string than returning an empty image since this will only obfuscate the underlying issue.